# Binary XML file line #14: error inflating class fragment // showing maps

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

## I was trying to show the maps in android application. I am using map V2. But the error "Binary XML file line #14: error inflating class fragment" is thrown. The app is crashed on launch.

Main activity java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap map;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
TextView tvDistanceDuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_distance_time);

    // Initializing 
    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
    map = fm.getMap();

    // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);     

    // Setting onclick event listener for the map
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

            // Already two locations                
            if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                markerPoints.clear();
                map.clear();                    
            }

            // Adding new item to the ArrayList
            markerPoints.add(point);                

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(point);

            /** 
             * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
             * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
             */
            if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }


            // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
            map.addMarker(options);

            // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
            if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){                   
                LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);                

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                downloadTask.execute(url);
            }

        }
    });

}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;      


    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";         

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


    return url;
}

// A method to download json data from url
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
 }



// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{         

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;        
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        super.onPostExecute(result);            

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }       
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject; 
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";



        if(result.size()<1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }


        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j); 

                if(j==0){   // Get distance from the list
                    distance = (String)point.get("distance");                       
                    continue;
                }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                    duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                points.add(position);                       
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);   

        }

        tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);                           
    }           
}   


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

### #activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_distance_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time" />
```

### #Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationdistancetimemapv2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<permission
                android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationdistancetimemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationdistancetimemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationdistancetimemapv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDtZuFHNcI9jxeoZy07k2D3ex10WM" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Casting the wrong class
use:

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

instand:

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

change it in the XML